# How to call another TestCase within a TestCase in Mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I'm using webdriver-io in combination with Mocha (and JavaScript). I came to a point where it would like to call a specific test case within another test case.

Assuming we have the following code:

```
describe('TestSuite', function(){

    it('TestCase A', function(){
        return browser
            .getTitle()
            .then( function(title) {
                (title).should.equal('title');
            });
    });

    it('TestCase B', function() {
        // call 'TestCase A'
    });
});
```

Is there a possibility to call the 'TestCase A' within the 'TestCase B'?
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mocha has no notion of "calling test cases". But you are using JavaScript and can take advantage of that. Make the common code into a function and call it from multiple tests:

```
describe('TestSuite', function(){

    function checkTitle() {
        return browser
            .getTitle()
            .then( function(title) {
                (title).should.equal('title');
            });
    }

    it('TestCase A', function() {
        return checkTitle();
    });

    it('TestCase B', function() {
        return checkTitle().then(...);
    });
});
```

Comment: your solution works.
Thanks a lot for your answer! :)